# Using FOR Loop and SC Query in CMD Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd

Suppose this instruction:

```
C:\>SC query state= all | find /I "adobe"
```

The result is:

```
SERVICE_NAME: AdobeARMservice
DISPLAY_NAME: Adobe Acrobat Update Service
```

Now I want to obtain the exact argument in this case is "AdobeARMservice"

Here my Script **TestLineArgument.bat**:

```
@echo off
cls
REM 
REM for /f "delims=" %%# in ('SC query state= all ^| find /I "adobe"') do ( IS NOT WORKING
REM 
set "SCQueryState=SC query state ^= all"
set "QueryAdobe=%SCQueryState%^^^| find /I ^"adobe^""
for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%QueryAdobe%") do (
    set "THERSERVICE_NAME=%%#"
    echo %%#
    goto :END_FORSCQUERY
)
:END_FORSCQUERY
REM show the Line "SERVICE_NAME: AdobeARMservice"
echo THERSERVICE_NAME:%THERSERVICE_NAME%

FOR /f "tokens=2" %%# IN ("%THERSERVICE_NAME%") DO (
    set "THESERVICE=%%#"
)
REM show the second part "AdobeARMservice"
echo THESERVICE:%THESERVICE%
```

My Script is not working, I don't know how use FOR with SC Command

Some clue?

Comment: to evaluate a command with `for /f`, enclose it in single qoutes. Simple example: `for /f %%a in ('dir') do echo %%a`

Comment: Is your goal to see if the string "AdobeARMservice" is in the output of the query state command, and if it is assign it to variable %THESERVICE% ?

Comment: Yes, because later to be used in other instruction...

Comment: Are you trying to see if it is running and if yes, do something with it? If so, there seem to be easier ways.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to test with SC...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Initialize variables
    set "serviceName="
    set "displayName="

    rem Execute the query and retrieve all the SERVICE_NAME lines and
    rem the line with the desired display name

    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('
        sc query state^= all ^| findstr /i /l /c:"SERVICE_NAME" /c:"Adobe"
    ') do if not defined displayName if "%%a"=="SERVICE_NAME:" (
        set "serviceName=%%b"
    ) else set "displayName=%%b" 

    rem Show retrieved data
    if defined displayName (
        echo %serviceName%
        echo %displayName%
    ) else echo Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

This method does not work in the manner you were trying to implement, as @MCND answer does, but if "AdobeARMservice" is **only** returned by sc query state when it is running, this may be useful.

It simply looks for the string "AdobeARMservice" and sets THESERVICE var to the result:  If "AdobeARMservice" **not** found, THESERVICE remains empty. If found it gets value=AdobeARMservice

```
@echo off
    Set "THESERVICE="
    For /f %%A in ('sc query state^= all ^| find /i "AdobeARMservice"') do set THESERVICE=%%A
        If "%THESERVICE%"=="" echo AdobeARMservice not found
        If NOT "%THESERVICE%"=="" echo THESERVICE: %THESERVICE%
        pause
```

Comment: My Example was centered in obtain part of line...
My porpouse is to extract the exact name, because sometimes depends of version... For this example not... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simply...

```
@echo off
set "SERVICE=Adobe"
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('sc query state^= all ^| find /I "%SERVICE%"') do (
    for /f "tokens=2" %%# in ("%%s") do (
        echo THESERVICE:%%#
    )
)
```

I tryng to avoid to change the code according to version something like : "Adobe3.2_1" or "Adobe3.2_5" or "Adobe4.5", this snippet of code only...